# Is it possible to prefix all paths in an OpenAPI 2.0 spec?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have Swagger specification for an API that looks something like this:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: my-api
  description: My API
  version: v1
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /v1/entry/check:
    post:
      ...
  /v1/entry/enter:
    post:
      ...
  /v1/exit/leave:
    post:
      ...
...
```

As you can see, every single path in `paths` is prefixed with `/v1/` as the spec describes version `v1` of the API (as you can also see in the `info.version` value).

I am wondering, is there a way to avoid repeating this prefix, i.e. **implicitly prefix all paths** with `/v1/`? Mainly, I want to do this to avoid any accidental misuse of the spec, i.e. entirely prevent adding another path without the prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0, you can specify the prefix as [`basePath`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/):

```yaml
basePath: /v1
paths:
  /entry/check:
    ...
  /entry/enter
    ...
```

In OpenAPI 3.x, the prefix is part of the API server URL specified by `servers[].url`:

```yaml
servers:
  - url: /v1  # or https://my.api.com/subpath/v1 if you need an absolute URL
paths:
  /entry/check:
    ...
  /entry/enter
    ...
```

Comment: That's very neat - thanks!

Comment: This only works in OpenAPI 2.0 but has been removed in V3.

Comment: @MarkusM OAS3 analog of `basePath` is `servers[].url`. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: @Helen The problem is, that if it's part of the server URL, it might be updated at runtime by the client and then the 'v1', which is part of the specification, would get lost. If one would switch to a spec v2 but not update the server url, they would still be pointing at the v1 url. To my knowledge, there is no good solution to that.

Comment: Maybe it's the generator I'm using, OpenAPI Generator Maven plugin, but using relative prefix for OpenAPI 3.X just caused the url to be interpreted as absolute.